# Creating series from a series of list using positional list memeber

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a string column. I need to create a new column with 3rd element after col1.split(' '). I tried

```
df['col1'].str.split(' ')[0]
```

but all I get is error.

Actually I need to turn col1 into multiple columns after spliting by " ".

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: can you please show me your dataframe and what type of output you want??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this df

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Lets say 2000 is greater than 5']})

```
    col
0   Lets say 2000 is greater than 5
```

You can split and use str accessor to get elements at different positions

```
df['third'] = df.col.str.split(' ').str[2]
df['fifth'] = df.col.str.split(' ').str[4]
df['last'] = df.col.str.split(' ').str[-1]

    col                             third   fifth   last
 0  Lets say 2000 is greater than 5 2000    greater 5
```

Comment: So I should treat it like a string though it is not a string? It feels so quirky, any place you would suggest to find more info on this ?

Comment: You mentioned in the  question that it's a strong column so I don't quite understood should I treat it as a string part. May be it will be more clear if you post some data. You can also read more about str methods here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: No, you get me right. I mean the .str after strip(). Thank you. I took me some time to get familiar with the structure of pgsql manual. looks pd's is no better. But still the strip().str[2] part looks weird to new users like me.

Comment: Yeah that even I agree, somehow strip()[2] feels more intuitive:)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:
    `df["third"] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[2])`